# Finding out what sets these bags belong to?

Tags: set-identification

I recently opened up a Sterilite box of LEGO from a garage sale to find some unopened bags.  How can I figure out what sets these belong to?

1. [image: Bag2]
2. [image: Another Bag2]
3. [image: Bag3]
4. [image: Another Bag3]
5. [image: Bag4]
6. [image: Bag5]
7. [image: Another Bag5]

The Bags have numbers on them if that helps...424R8 is on a Bag 2 and a Bag 4.  324R8 is on Bag3 and a Bag 5.  211R7 is on a Bag2.  407R8 is on Bag 3.  450R6 is on a Bag 5.

Comment: It might be possible to identify sets from given pictures, however it would also make things a little easier if you upload higher resolution versions.

Comment: Ok. I will try to upload better pictures later. For what it is worth, I know there are some bricks in the container from the sets (76078 Hulk v. Red Hulk; 70320 Nexo Knights; 41587 Brickheadz Robin; 60119 City Ferry; 71006 The Simpsons House; and 75292 Star Wars Disney The Razor Crest (I believe).

Answer (score 6):

Based on

- [PLATE OCTAGONAL 10X10 W. SNAP](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4583688)
- [PLATE OCTAGONAL 10X10](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6172931)
- Scrolling through the instructions

First bag 2, first bag 3, bag 4 and first bag 5 (pictures 1, 3, 5 and 6) are from [75953: Hogwarts Whomping Willow](https://brickset.com/sets/75953-1/Hogwarts-Whomping-Willow)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Second bag #3 is from [75933: T. Rex Transport](https://brickset.com/sets/75933-1/T-Rex-Transport)

Key part : [Torso Female Jacket with Silver Zipper, Light Nougat Neck, Bright Light Orange Shirt with Dark Red Raptor Pattern / Olive Green Arms / Light Nougat Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb3154c01&idColor=155#T=C&C=155)

- Second bag #5 is from [21134: The Waterfall Base](https://brickset.com/sets/21134-1/The-Waterfall-Base)

Key parts : [Plate 6 x 12 in Bright Green](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3028&colorID=36&in=A)
, [White Brick 2 x 10](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?itemType=P&itemNo=3006&in=A&v=1&oV=Y&colorID=1&srt=2&srtAsc=D) and [Red Apple](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33051&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)